# webpack always generates non empty file and gives error about WebSocket connection failed

Tags: javascript, webpack, websocket, webpack-dev-server

I am new to webpack and just started using it with local server development for new ES6 compatible javascript syntax and for scss compilation.

My webpack.config.js looks like this.

```
const path = require('path');
const devMiddleware = require("webpack-dev-middleware");
const MiniCssExtractPlugin = require("mini-css-extract-plugin");
var BrowserSyncPlugin = require('browser-sync-webpack-plugin');
const dev = process.env.NODE_ENV !== 'production'



module.exports = {
  devtool: 'source-map', 
  plugins: [
    new MiniCssExtractPlugin({filename: './css/[name].css'}),
    
  ],
  entry: {
    app: {import: './src/js/app.js', filename: "./js/[name].js"},
    'custom': {import: './src/scss/custom.scss'},
    
  },
  output: {
    path: path.resolve(__dirname, './dist/'),
    filename: "./js/[name].js",
  },
  devServer: {
    //https: true,
    static: path.resolve(__dirname, './'),
    port: 8080,
    hot: true,
    //liveReload: false,
    //watchFiles: 'node_modules/**/*',
    devMiddleware: {
      index: true,
      mimeTypes: { phtml: 'text/html' },
      serverSideRender: true,
      writeToDisk: true,
    },
  },
  module: {
    rules: [
      {
        test: /\.(scss)$/,
        use: [
          {
            
            loader: 'style-loader',
          },
          {
            loader: MiniCssExtractPlugin.loader,
            options: {
              esModule: false,
            },
          },
          {
            
            loader: 'css-loader',
            options: {
              sourceMap: true,
            },
          },
         
          {
            loader: 'sass-loader',
            options: {
              implementation: require("sass"),
              sourceMap: true,
            },
          },
          
        ]
      },
      {
        test: /\.(ttf|woff|woff2)$/,
        exclude: /node_modules/,
        type: 'asset/resource',
        generator: {
          filename: 'fonts/[name][ext]'
        }
      }
    ]
  },
  snapshot: {
    managedPaths: [],
  }
};
```

and I am using npm start script to start the server and see the changes in browser and everything is working fine.

However when i stopped the server and directly open `index.html` (where resulting `dist/app.js` is linked via link tag) file via file protocol in browser I am getting this error.

`WebSocket connection to 'ws://0.0.0.0:8080/ws' failed:`

I noticed even when I am keeping `src/app.js` file completely empty,  still a lot of code comes pre-generated from webpack in `dist/app.js` and I am not getting how this is being handled.

I thought if I stopped the server and open `index.html` directly, it would work same and webpack is only used here for compilation here but that is not the case and it generates much more than that which I don't understand how. I even tried removing `devServer` entry entirely and recompiled `app.js` again but with same result.

Can anyone please help on this topic? Also, How can I generate only empty file if source is empty?